# Selecting id attribute using xpath/scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to select the user name from the following [forum url](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=22232).

However, when I use the following in the scrapy shell:

```
admin:~/workspace/scrapper (master) $ scrapy shell "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=22232"
In [1]: response.xpath('//*[@id='bodyarea']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')
  File "<ipython-input-4-abe70514018b>", line 1
    response.xpath('//*[@id='bodyarea']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, in Chrome the selector works fine.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of quotes inconsistent usage. Note that you're using single quotes both for XPath and string inside XPath.

Use either

```
'//*[@id="bodyarea"]/table...'
```

or

```
"//*[@id='bodyarea']/table..."
```

Comment: To add to that you can also escape the quotes with backslash : `'//*[@id=\'bodyarea\']/table...'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I now get via the scrapy console `[]` back. Any suggestions why this is the case? I appreciate your reply!

Comment: @Anna.Klee , try to use this XPath `//td[.="Name:"]/following-sibling::td`

Comment: @Andersson Thank you for your reply! However, using scrapy console I still get the following output: `In [8]: response.xpath('//td[.="Name:"]/following-sibling::td').extract()
Out[8]: []` Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?`

Comment: @Anna.Klee , Yeah, right. This one `'//td[normalize-space(.)="Name:"]/following-sibling::td'` should work